# Где найти Android Studio 32 bit

Tags: android-studio

Где можно скачать Android Studio 32-х битной версии? Не смог найти, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/install тут же всё написано. https://developer.android.com/studio#downloads а тут качаемо

Comment: Вам нужно поработать над выражением своих мыслей словами, иначе у вас будут большие проблемы с поиском информации и получением ответов на вопросы. "Не могу скачать" и "не смог найти" совсем не одно и то же.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю суть вопроса именно в этой части **32 bit**. Насколько я вижу, на офф сайте в требованиях такая картина:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь вы можете скачать только Android Studio **64 bit**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот я набрел на [инструкцию](https://developer.android.com/studio/install#windows) по установке от Google:

> If you downloaded a .zip file, unpack the ZIP, copy the android-studio
> folder into your Program Files folder, and then open the
> android-studio > bin folder and launch studio64.exe (for 64-bit
> machines) or studio.exe (for 32-bit machines).

я думаю переводить не нужно все чтобы понять что вам нужно скачать архив где будет инсталлятор. Возникает вопрос где взять архив - он есть в вариантах загрузки на сайте, можно попробовать, хотя там написано что только для 64-битных ПК. Вот попался такой же [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659387/how-to-install-android-studio-when-os-is-32-bit) где есть [ссылка на установщик](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.1.0/android-studio-ide-171.4443003-windows32.zip)